# how to declare global float register for ARMCC

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, arm, cortex-m

For a power conversion application we need to do various floating point calculations as quickly as possible on an ARM Cortex-M4 platform.

We are developing with Keil uVision.

We would like to declare some variables as register variables but get nothing but errors from the compiler.

Seems like this is something that would be very useful, as the FPU has 32 registers, and we could save a lot of cycles by storing our data in these registers rather than reloading from RAM every time our ISR is called.

We tried using:

```
register float a1 __asm__("s0");
```

but receive an error: unknown register name "s0"

It seems odd, because in the debugger interface I can see that the compiler is using the s0 register. If I declare the register as "r0" instead, there is no error, so it seems like there is some missing FPU support somewhere, but not sure where.

I look at the Assembler control string and seems like floating point is supported:

```
--cpu Cortex-M4.fp --pd "__EVAL SETA 1" -g --apcs=interwork 
-I D:\my_project
-I D:\Keil_v5\ARM\PACK\ARM\CMSIS\4.4.0\CMSIS\Include
```

We also tried:

```
__global_freg(1) float a1;
```

This didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using armcc?  The [ARMCC manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/chr1359125006491.html) lists the FPU registers that can be named, and the list doesn't include the sX or dX registers.

Comment: yes I am using ARMCC and I saw that. We also tried compiling with gcc and got the error: register specified for 'a1' isn't suitable for data type

Comment: The gcc versions on [gcc.godbolt.org work](http://goo.gl/iRXWtr) though.

Comment: I see [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472e/Cihedead.html) that the compiler does support VFP instructions in inline assembly. But if we write the routines in assembler, then how can we stop the compiler from clobbering our registers somewhere else?

Comment: @Jester thanks for a very interesting point. I tried with arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.8.4. The compiler on godbolt is arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.5. Maybe that is relevant? I'm not sure whether we could use this version, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Also 4.8.2 is available in the drop-down and that works too.

Comment: And it works in Atollic TrueSTUDIO with arm-atollic-eabi-gcc. But the Atollic code runs terribly slowly compared to the code from the MDK-ARM compiler.

Comment: I discovered that only registers s16 through s31 can be used without risk of clobbering with a gcc compiler. With Atollic my interrupt execution time went from 4.85 uS down to 1.15 uS, which was a significant improvement indeed. However, if we were able to use 22 registers instead of 16, the interrupt would execute in less than 500 nS. Probably this could be done with MDK-ARM and inline assembly, but I don't know how to prevent register clobbering there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to abide by the EABI, detailed here:  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf

From perusing it, it appears you can use (as mentioned in your comment above) s16-s31.  The rest are not guaranteed to be preserved by other code.

If your application processing allows, you could possibly get around this by only compiling your ISR with VFP support, and everything else without.  This would prevent any code you don't know about from using the VFP registers and corrupting them.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea! I will try that.